# Struts - Passing parameters between action

Tags: java, struts2

I have got two actions - ActionA and ActionB, Im trying to invoke ActionB from the result of ActionA using '**action**' tag in the following way

```
 <s:action namespace="/myNameSpace" name="actionB"  executeResult="true">
 <s:param name="param1" value="Value1"/></s:action>
```

The tag is invoking 'actionB' and Im getting the result from ActionB included into the result of ActionA as I expected. But Im not able to bind the parameter 'param1' to the property in the ActionB. Is it possible to pass parameters to another action in this fashion? I badly need to bind the parameters from this jsp to my action. Please help :(

Answer (score 1):

The value for "param1" in your example is fixed. You need to use something like

<`s:param name="param1" value="%{value1}"/>`

instead.